# .Net Core WebAPI : use different json serializer option to deserialize request body in the same controller

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, jsonserializer

I'm creating a .Net Core WebAPI (3.1) which need the ability to change its json serializer settings according to the type of the request body.
I'm using Json.Net instead of System.Text.json.

```cs
public class MyController
{
    public virtual ActionResult<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetFilteredEntities(int maxNResults, [FromBody] IFilter<TEntity> filter)
    ...
    public virtual ActionResult<TEntity> Update([FromBody] TEntity entity)
}
```

In my sample, TEntity needs to be serialized with a settings that contains the PreserveReferencesHandling option but IFilter must not.
I found many solutions to be able to switch json options for the response but nothing for the request. How can I achieve my goal please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside each controller method. Responce or Request, if they have a type you can serialize them.

in `GetFilteredEntities`,

```
var Settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Object
};
var TheJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filter, filter.GetType().BaseType, Settings);
```

In `Update`,

```
var Settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All
};
var TheJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity, entity.GetType().BaseType, Settings);
```

Comment: I have several endpoints in several controllers, I search a solution that don't force me to treat each action by hand

Comment: @Karine see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927358/custom-jsonserializersettings-jsonconverter-for-list-of-different-types-each-t

Comment: I think it could be the nicer and the least expensive solution